# swift - How to perform task completion

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do reverse geocoding for multiple locations at the same time. So I create a function `performReverseGeoLocation`. The problem is, that since `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` a closure, the `completionHandlerLocations` will get executed first. How do I change these functions so that the caller will get completion handler after all `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` inside the for loop is done?

**Code I have tried:**

```
private func getImageLocation() {
    performReverseGeoLocation(completionHandlerLocations: { (cities, countries) in
        print("***** This is executed before the reverse geo code location is done")
    })
}

private func performReverseGeoLocation(completionHandlerLocations: @escaping (_ cities: [String], _ countries: [String]) -> Void) {

    var cities = [String]()
    var countries = [String]()

    for image in self.images {
        let longitude = image.longitude
        let latitude = image.latitude

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            print("***** This is executed after completionHandlerLocations is done")
            if error != nil {
                self.alertError("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]

                let country = pm.country
                let city = pm.locality


                if (!cities.contains(city!)) {
                    cities.append(city!)
                }

                if (!countries.contains(country!)) {
                    countries.append(country!)
                }
            }
            else {
                self.alertError("Fail to perform reverse geo location")
            }
        })
    }
    // THIS IS WILL EXECUTED FIRST
    completionHandlerLocations(cities, countries)
}
```

Comment: One possible solution is to create a dispatch group, have each inner block enter and leave the dispatch group, then invoke your final completionHandlerLocations() when everyone has left the group.  E.g.: http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/

Comment: Thanks @i_am_jorf. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var count = 0

for image in self.images {
     ...
     CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
          // get result 

          counter ++

          if count == self.images.count { // finish all requests
               completionHandlerLocations(cities, countries)
          }

     }
}
```

That's the most simple way to do.

Comment: Daniel Tran. Thanks for the suggestion. But for some reason it does not work. The for loop will keep going, and the completionHandlerLocation will be called x times where x is the self.images.count.

Answer (score 0):

As *i-am-jorf* mentioned, you can create a DispatchGroup and wait for the notification when all reverse geocoding tasks are complete:

```
private func performReverseGeoLocation(completionHandlerLocations: @escaping (_ cities: [String], _ countries: [String]) -> Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    var cities = [String]()
    var countries = [String]()

    self.images.forEach { (location) in
        group.enter()

        let longitude = image.longitude
        let latitude = image.latitude
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) in
            // do all your checks...
            if placemark != nil && placemark!.count > 0 {
                cities.append(placemark!.first!.locality!)
                countries.append(placemark!.first!.country!)
            }

            group.leave()
        })
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        completionHandlerLocations(cities, countries)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I guess DispatchGroup is like a reference counter? Because we call enter() and leave x times...